# Firebase - order by custom function (distance)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I have a list in firebase, that includes geolocation (longitude and latitude), and I want to get the 10 closest places to a given coordinate.

I am transitioning from MySQL, where in there I would calculate the distance in the `SELECT`, and order by it in `ORDER BY`.

If I can't do it from the firebase SDK, is there a way to perhaps add a custom function?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with firebase's [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) methods. You probably want to use [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) if you want more details I can write an answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I really like the Observable / data stream way, if that is possible with cloud functions as well, I would love a more detailed answer.

Comment: Looking for long and lat data format I've found this that may be what are you looking for: [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire). Let me know if this is what you wanted ;)

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thanks a lot. I will have a deeper look soon, but it seems like what I need

Comment: @DevidFarinelli While that was extremely helpful, do you mind writing an answer with a function example for this?

Comment: Ok :) Gonna work on it this evening. Can you please provide an example of how are your long and lat values saved on firebase?

Comment: Thanks! Every item in the list has `coordinates: {longitude, latitude}`, and the current user coordinate can be sent to the function, or fetched from `users/$uid/coordinates`. I just got lost in all of the functions stuff, and can't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this as request-response like what is explained [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html) using cloud functions this way:

1. The client pushes a request in `closest/requests/requestID`. You can [push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) an object like `requestID: {long: 'xxx', lat: 'xxxxx' }`

   ```
   functions.database.ref('/closest/requests').push({
       latitude: 'youlat',
       longitude: 'yourlong'
   });
   ```
2. A cloud function [listens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) `closest/requests` for new requests and sets the response to `closest/responses/requestID`

   ```
   functions.database.ref('closest/requests/{requestID}')
   .onCreate(event => {
       const request = event.data.val()
       const response = getClosest(request.latitude, request.longitude)
       functions.database.ref('closest/responses/' + event.params.requestID)
       .set({
           response: response
       })
   }
   ```

`getClosest` should be a function that looks at the data in the database and calculates which are the 10 closest places.

I've not tested if this code works but I think it is enough to understand how to implement this. Let me know if you need further help :)

Comment: I like it. Thanks! I will mutate this to use geofire, as I understand it is faster for my use case, and can work in real time sort of.